# Resume fragment from non parent activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, onresume, activity-finish

I have a landing activity with 3 fragments in it. It has a create button on action bar, on its click another activity is launched with dialog theme. After doing stuff in it, I'm calling .finish() method so that the landing activity is resumed with the middle fragment as selected.
Now how to call my custom on refresh method on the middle fragment after it has resumed?

Comment: Use OnActivityResult() in your activity, or onResume() in your fragment.

Comment: @cha122977 onActivityResult will be used to go to activity with result code but how to tell the fragment then when to load. Also if using onResume in fragment directly it works but, I want to execute that method only when it is returned from create activity and not from other activity. Currently executing onResume results in fragment resuming and executing custom method when returning from any other activity also.

Comment: I think you should use onActivityResult. You can save the instance of Fragment in Activity, and use fragment.someFunciton() to call the function directly.